# What is this New Zealand insect and what is it in?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

What kind of insect is this?
[image: Picture of Insect]
[image: Picture of Insect]
Found in Early September at Jubilee Park, Dunedin, New Zealand. It was suspended from a silk thread (quite long, a few meters) to a tree above. It was climbing the thread, balling the thread as it went up. It looks like a caterpillar. What species is this and what is it inside of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quality of the pictures is not the best one, but due to the fact that this is NZ, it's probably a moth from the species *[Liothula omnivora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liothula_omnivora)*.

It's a kiwi insect (that is, endemic to New Zealand). Its English common name is bagworm, and its Maori common name is pū a Raukatauri. The English name explains your question (*"what is it in?"*). According to [Farm Forestry New Zealand](http://www.nzffa.org.nz/farm-forestry-model/the-essentials/forest-health-pests-and-diseases/Pests/Liothula-omnivora):

> The common name of this insect refers to the strong silk bag made as a refuge by the caterpillar. The bag is brown to greyish, often covered with fragments of vegetation, and so tough it cannot be torn open.

Here is a picture of it:

[image]

And here is the adult, for comparison:

[image]